# Jquery set defaults for all instances of a plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Given the following plugin how would you set defaults for all the instances? I would like it to work the same as $.datepicker.setDefaults().

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.borderSwitcher = function(options) {
        defaults = {
            borderColor: 'Black',
            borderWidth: '1px',
            borderStyle: 'solid'
        };

        return this.each(function() {

            var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

            $(this).focus(function() {
                //find a better way to set border properties
                var props = settings.borderStyle + ' ' + settings.borderWidth + ' ' + settings.borderColor;
                $(this).css('border', props);
            });

            $(this).blur(function() {
                $(this).css('border', '');
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: in-order to use defaults , u can pass the empty object in extend as below

$.extend({},defaults,options);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them at jQuery object iteself:

```
(function ($) {
    $.borderSwitcher.defaults = { //NOTE: no fn here
        borderColor: 'Black',
        borderWidth: '1px',
        borderStyle: 'solid'
    };

    $.fn.borderSwitcher = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend($.borderSwitcher.defaults, options);

        //the rest of your code
    }

};

//And outside your plugin definition, set the default for all new instances
$.borderSwitcher.defaults.borderWidth = '2px';

$('.foo').borderSwitcher(); //with 2px
$('.foo').borderSwitcher({borderWidth:'3px'}); //with 3px
```